# Checking Build Errors to be included in a solution build so that if there is any error in sql file the build fails

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a c# project  which is a console application , it uses DbUp for running the scripts to a sql server db , Is there a way to stop the build process if there is any syntax issue in .sql file

I tried several ways of doing it, changing the project file to do it via MS build but did not succeed

Comment: that depends on how you call that script. Does it provide any exit-code?

Comment: Are you using the [`Exec` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022) in MSBuild to run your console app and the console app is using DbUp?

Comment: You can take a look of my answer, sqlcmd has an argument -b which can block the batch and exit when encounter issue. Set the validate step before the build step, you can achieve the requirement you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have, you can check whether the script work before build the project.

Just like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--This is the key part-->
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xxx" />
  </Target>
  <!--This is the key part-->

</Project>
```

Replace the command xxx to the validate script.

For example:

`sqlcmd -S xxx -d xxx -U your_username -P your_password -i "xxx" -b`

[Official Document Of Sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=odbc%2Cwindows&pivots=cs1-bash)

-b will terminate batch job if there is an error in this situation.